# file name and path manipulation using perl

Tags: arrays, regex, linux, perl, file

I am having following code. It is working fine but i am trying to make it more generic.

What code does:
It loops through an array provided from somewhere as input. Array has values which are path to files.

For example: /path/to/file/location/ABC_XYZ12345678912_120215_010018654_PQR-HWL-Datafile.tar.gz

Now it takes each element in array and tries to remove the first part of file name which "ABC_XYZ12345678912_120215_010018654_" and then create a new copy of file with same path but file name having just the last part. For example:
/path/to/file/location/PQR-HWL-Datafile.tar.gz.

Starting part of file name will always be like above ( pattern wise ) that is ABC_14DigitAlphanumric_monthdateyearpatter(6 digits)_9digit more.

Code is working fine.

Now i have two questions for below code.

1> How can make the part where i extract last part of file name more generic as compared doing some hard coded stuff like:  ( use of some regular expression or something like that )

```
my ( $file, $dir ) = fileparse($individualFile);

# how this part can be made more generic so that i can directly extract the name of last part of file as compared doing hard code comparison 
if ( $file =~ 'PQR-HWL-Datafile.tar.gz' ) {
   $newFileName = "PQR-HWL-Datafile.tar.gz";
}elsif ( $file =~ 'data_value_most_recent.bin.gz' ){
   $newFileName = "data_value_most_recent.bin.gz";
}

my $absPathToNewFile = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, $newFileName );
```

2> Secondly copy operation becomes something like below or can be avoided creating the copy:

copy( $individualFile, $absPathToNewFile );   =======>  ( becomes something like this or less hard coded )

copy( File_with_original_name, File_with_new_file_name

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use File::Copy;

my @filePathArray =     
('/path/to/file/location/ABC_XYZ12345678912_120215_010018654_PQR-HWL-
```

Datafile.tar.gz','/path/to/file/location/ABC_XYZ12345678912_120215_010018654_da ta_value_most_recent.bin.gz');

```
my $newFileName;
foreach my $individualFile (@filePathArray) {

  my ( $file, $dir ) = fileparse($individualFile);

  if ( $file =~ 'PQR-HWL-Datafile.tar.gz' ) {
     $newFileName = "PQR-HWL-Datafile.tar.gz";
  }elsif ( $file =~ 'data_value_most_recent.bin.gz' ){
     $newFileName = "data_value_most_recent.bin.gz";
  }

  my $absPathToNewFile = File::Spec->catfile( $dir, $newFileName );
  copy( $individualFile, $absPathToNewFile );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you know your pattern you can simply write regex for it and substitute it with empty string, just like this:

```
my $old_filename = "ABC_XYZ12345678912_120215_123456789_PQR-HWL-Datafile.tar.gz";

# pattern described in the question
my $pattern = qr/^ABC_[A-Za-z0-9]{14}_\d{6}_\d{9}_/;

( my $new_filename = $old_filename ) =~ s/$pattern//;

print "new_filename: $new_filename\n";
print "old_filename: $old_filename\n";
```

2) I don't see anything wrong with copy part. Maybe I didn't get the question.

Comment: your case for regular expression should handle the case for both names otheriwse what is the point of having regular expression. In that case hard coded one as i have shown above will be working fine

Comment: I just checked your solution works for any pattern in the end. Does not matter if its _ or -. You should remove the else condition and then i will be able to accept your answer

Comment: else condition is confusing here

Comment: @user1188611 ah, missed the `elsif ( $file =~ 'data_value_most_recent.bin.gz' )` part in your code, thought it was just `else`. Thanks for mentioning that.